# Joomla 1.5 : index page contents to some menu item links only

Tags: php, joomla

Mostly we found in template there is already in `index.php` which shows in all page for eg.

```
<h1 class="logo-text">
<a href="index.php" title="<?php echo $siteName; ?>">
  <span><?php echo $logoText; ?></span>
</a>
</h1>
<p class="site-slogan"><?php echo $sloganText;?></p>
```

will display in all pages. But I would like to know that could I assign this to some menu items only, using php?

Comment: why - vote? please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in if-clause using Itemid of the request.
Or you can replace it with custom position, load that content in a custom-html module and assign it to some menu items only

Comment: could you please show me an example of itemid using if clause.